# How to publish scalatest results to vso in BuildVnext?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We are hosting our Scala and java code in git repo in vso and using maven tool to do continuous builds using build vnext. We use junit to write tests for Java code and scalatest for writings tests for Scala code. 
Our junit tests seem to be executed as part of build and results stored on vso but I don't see Scala tests being executed as part of build. They do executed when I run mvn  package command locally, so I'm sure that the pom is correctly configured.

How to get scalatest based unit tests run as part of vso build?

Comment: How do you call scalatest in Maven? Use the scaletest maven plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out. I need to use the junitrunner to execute the scalatest based unit tests, so that VSO can detect the results. Here's how you need to annotate the test class to use Junit runner.
http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_junit_runner